# Zend Framework 2 & PHPUnit - mock the Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter class

Tags: unit-testing, zend-framework, zend-framework2, mocking, phpunit

I started learning Zend Framework a couple of years ago following [this tutorial](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/getting-started-with-zend-studio/the-application.html). In there, it shows mappers are created using the `Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter` class to get the database connection, and that is how I've worked with databases since with no issues.

I'm now trying to learn how to use PHPUnit on Zend applications, and am running into difficulties in testing the functions in the mapper as I'm unable to mock the `Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter` class.

[This tutorial](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/tutorials/unittesting.html) on the Zend website shows mocking database connections, but it uses the `Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway` class. All other tutorials I've found online use this class too, and the only thing I've found regarding the `Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter` class is [this](https://gist.github.com/b-durand/3408307):

```
$date = new DateTime();
$mockStatement = $this->getMock('Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Statement');
$mockStatement->expects($this->once())->method('execute')->with($this->equalTo(array(
    'timestamp' => $date->format(FormatterInterface::DEFAULT_DATETIME_FORMAT)
)));

$mockDbDriver = $this->getMockBuilder('Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Pdo')
    ->disableOriginalConstructor()
    ->getMock();

$mockDbAdapter = $this->getMock('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter', array(), array($mockDbDriver));
$mockDbAdapter->expects($this->once())
    ->method('query')
    ->will($this->returnValue($mockStatement));
```

I've tried putting that into my `setUp` method but running `phpunit` on the test class gives me the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function createStatement() on null in C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\test_project\vendor\zendframework\zend-db\src\Sql\Sql.php on line 128

**So my question is, how do you mock the `Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter` class in PHPUnit?**

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34225052/zf2-phpunit-mock-a-zend-db-adapter-adapter-for-further-usage) which is similar, but uses a `Zend/Db/Adapter/AdapterInterface` instead, and I can't seem to translate that code into my situation. Mapper and test class code below.

**ProductMapper.php:**

```
public function __construct(Adapter $dbAdapter) {
    $this->dbAdapter = $dbAdapter;
    $this->sql = new Sql($dbAdapter);
}

public function fetchAllProducts() {
    $select = $this->sql->select('products');

    $statement = $this->sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($select);
    $results = $statement->execute();

    $hydrator = new ClassMethods();
    $product = new ProductEntity();
    $resultset = new HydratingResultSet($hydrator, $product);
    $resultset->initialize($results);
    $resultset->buffer();

    return $resultset;
}
```

**ProductMapperTest.php:**

```
public function setUp() {
    $date = new DateTime();

    $mockStatement = $this->getMock('Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Statement');
    $mockStatement->expects($this->once())->method('execute')->with($this->equalTo(array(
            'timestamp' => $date->format(FormatterInterface::DEFAULT_DATETIME_FORMAT)
    )));

    $mockDbDriver = $this->getMockBuilder('Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Pdo')->disableOriginalConstructor()->getMock();

    $this->mockDbAdapter = $this->getMock('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter', array(), array(
            $mockDbDriver
    ));
    $this->mockDbAdapter->expects($this->once())->method('query')->will($this->returnValue($mockStatement));
}

public function testFetchAllProducts() {
    $resultsSet = new ResultSet();

    $productMapper = new ProductMapper($this->mockDbAdapter);

    $this->assertSame($resultsSet, $productMapper->fetchAllProducts());
}
```

---

**EDIT #1:**

Following on from Wilt's answer, I changed my mapper to use the `Sql` class in the constructor and changed my Test class to:

```
public function setUp() {
    $mockSelect = $this->getMock('Zend\Db\Sql\Select');

    $mockDbAdapter = $this->getMockBuilder('Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterInterface')->disableOriginalConstructor()->getMock();

    $this->mockStatement = $this->getMock('Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Statement');

    $this->mockSql = $this->getMock('Zend\Db\Sql\Sql', array('select', 'prepareStatementForSqlObject'), array($mockDbAdapter));
    $this->mockSql->method('select')->will($this->returnValue($mockSelect));
    $this->mockSql->method('prepareStatementForSqlObject')->will($this->returnValue($this->mockStatement));
}

public function testFetchAllProducts() {
    $resultsSet = new ResultSet();

    $this->mockStatement->expects($this->once())->method('execute')->with()->will($this->returnValue($resultsSet));

    $productMapper = new ProductMapper($this->mockSql);

    $this->assertSame($resultsSet, $productMapper->fetchAllProducts());
}
```

However, I now get the following error:

> ProductTest\Model\ProductMapperTest::testFetchAllProducts
>   Failed asserting that two variables reference the same object.

Which is coming from the line `$this->assertSame($resultsSet, $productMapper->fetchAllProducts());`. Have I mocked something incorrectly?

---

**Edit #2:**

As suggested by Wilt, I changed the test class to use a `StatementInterface` to mock a statement instead, so the code now looks like:

```
public function setUp() {

    $mockSelect = $this->getMock('Zend\Db\Sql\Select');

    $mockDbAdapter = $this->getMockBuilder('Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterInterface')->disableOriginalConstructor()->getMock();

    $this->mockStatement = $this->getMock('Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\StatementInterface');

    $this->mockSql = $this->getMock('Zend\Db\Sql\Sql', array('select', 'prepareStatementForSqlObject'), array($mockDbAdapter));
    $this->mockSql->method('select')->will($this->returnValue($mockSelect));
    $this->mockSql->method('prepareStatementForSqlObject')->will($this->returnValue($this->mockStatement));

}

public function testFetchAllProducts() {
    $resultsSet = new ResultSet();

    $this->mockStatement->expects($this->once())->method('execute')->with()->will($this->returnValue($resultsSet));

    $productMapper = new ProductMapper($this->mockSql);

    $this->assertSame($resultsSet, $productMapper->fetchAllProducts());
}
```

But the test case is still failing as above. I haven't changed the line of code which is mocking the `execute` method as I believe it was already returning `$resultsSet`, however I could be wrong!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe it would be better here to change the `__construct` method to take an `Sql` instance as an argument. It seems like the `$dbAdapter` is only used inside the constructor and because of this it seems to me that the actual dependency for your `ProductMapper` class is not an `Adapter` instance, but rather a `Sql` instance. If you make that change you only need to mock the `Sql` class inside your `ProductMapperTest`.

If you don't want to make such a change inside your code and you still want to continue writing a test for the current `ProductMapper` class you should also mock all the other methods of the `Adapter` class that the `Sql` class is calling internally.

Right now you call `$this->sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($select);` on your `Sql` instance which internally calls the `createStatement` method of the `Adapter` class (you can see that [here on line **128** inside the `Sql` class](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-db/blob/master/src/Sql/Sql.php#L125-L131)). But in your case the `Adapter` is a mock and that is why the error is thrown:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function `createStatement()` on null in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\test_project\vendor\zendframework\zend-db\src\Sql\Sql.php` on line **128**

So to solve this you should mock this method too similarly to how you did for the `query` method:

```
$mockStatement = //...your mocked statement...
$this->mockDbAdapter->expects($this->once())
                    ->method('createStatement')
                    ->will($this->returnValue($mockStatement));
```

In the next line you call `$statement->execute();` meaning you will also need to mock the `execute` method inside your `$mockStatement`.

As you see the writing this test becomes pretty cumbersome. And you should ask yourself if you are on the right path and testing the right components. You could make some small design changes (improvements) that makes it easier to test your `ProductMapper` class.

Comment: Great answer thanks, pointed me in the right direction changing the dependency to use an `Sql` instance. I've now got rid of the error message, but the test itself is failing where I'd expect it to pass. I've added new code to the question if you wouldn't mind taking a look? I'm not sure if I've mocked something wrong, or it's just my lack of experience in unit testing and I'm incorrectly assuming the test to pass!

Comment: @Crazyloonybin It would be enough to use a `StatementInterface` to mock a statement (there is no need to need a specific adapter class for this). Then you need to mock the `execute` method in this `$mockStatement` and the return value of this method should be the `$resultsSet`. Then your test should pass.

Comment: I've changed the statement to read `$this->mockStatement = $this->getMock('Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\StatementInterface');` but I'm still getting the same error. I've kept the `$this->mockStatement` code the same as what's shown in the question edit, with the `testFetchAllProducts` function returning `$resultsSet` - does this line need modifying too?

Comment: That's supposed to be `execute` function instead of `testFetchAllProducts` function - I waited too long to edit!

Comment: @crazyloonybin Inside your `fetchAllProducts` method you still do a lot of other things with the `$results`. After this line `$results = $statement->execute();` you still do (among other things) `$resultset = new HydratingResultSet($hydrator, $product);` and then you `return $resultset` meaning you have a instance of `HydratingResultSet` which is something else then the `ResultSet` you mocked in your statement.

Comment: Sorry, yes that makes perfect sense, I was taking the tutorial too literally instead of applying it to my situation. I think I'll be able to get it working from what you've said, otherwise I'll start a new question. Thanks for all your help! :)

Comment: @crazyloonybin The test should be `assertEqual()` rather than `assertSame()`. The result set *instance* will always be different from the returned method as you cannot mock `$resultset = new HydratingResultSet($hydrator, $product);`. It is a new instance every time. If however you encapsulate the the creation of the result set in another method `$resultSet = $this->createNewResultSet($hydrator, $entity);` you would then be able to stub that method and test using `assertSame($resultSet, $productMapper->fetchAllProducts())`.

Comment: @AlexP Thanks Alex, eventually I went down the route of `assertInstanceOf()` to make sure that I was getting an instance of `HydratingResultSet`, but what you said about extracting the code into a new function and stubbing that looks like a good route too!